# How to create a custom generic view from a web2py RESTFUL service?

Tags: python, html, rest, model-view-controller, web2py

Using Web2Py RESTFUL services, I'd like the following html to render in the browser after navigating to this link (http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/default/api/example_data.html_table/?limit=1):

```
<div><table><thead><tr><th>example_data.id</th><th>example_data.Firstname</th><th>example_data.Lastname</th><th>example_data.Age</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="w2p_odd odd"><td>1</td><td>SUUUUPPPEEEERRRR LONGGGGG FIRSTTTT NAMEEEE</td><td>Smith</td><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

However, I currently receive the following:

```
<div><table><thead><tr><th>example_data.id</th><th>example_data.Firstname</th><th>example_data.Lastname</th><th>example_data.Age</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="w2p_odd odd"><td>1</td><td>SUUUUPPPEEEER...</td><td>Smith</td><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

The difference is that Web2Py is shortening "SUUUUPPPEEEERRRR LONGGGGG FIRSTTTT NAMEEEE" to "SUUUUPPPEEEER..." but I need the entire text

My View called generic.html_table that generates this is the following:

```
{{=BEAUTIFY(response._vars[next(iter(response._vars))])}}
```

Controller

```
@request.restful()
def api():
    response.view = 'generic.' + request.extension
    def GET(*args,**vars):
        patterns = 'auto'
        parser = db.parse_as_rest(patterns,args,vars)
        return dict(content=parser.response)
    def POST(table_name,**vars):
        if 'id' in vars.keys():
            return db[table_name].update_or_insert(db[table_name]._id == vars['id'],**vars)
        else:
            return db[table_name].validate_and_insert(**vars)
    def PUT(table_name,**vars):
        record_id = vars['id']
        return db(db[table_name]._id==record_id).update(**vars)
    def DELETE(table_name,record_id):
        return db(db[table_name]._id==record_id).delete()
    return dict(GET=GET, POST=POST, PUT=PUT, DELETE=DELETE)
```

MODEL

```
db.define_table('example_data', Field('Firstname', 'string'),Field('Lastname', 'string'),Field('Age', 'integer'))
```

I've also tried the following views:

```
{{=response._vars[next(iter(response._vars))]}}
```

RESULT (first name still cut off):

```
<table><thead><tr><th>example_data.id</th><th>example_data.Firstname</th><th>example_data.Lastname</th><th>example_data.Age</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="w2p_odd odd"><td>1</td><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>1</td></tr><tr class="w2p_even even"><td>2</td><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>33</td></tr><tr class="w2p_odd odd"><td>3</td><td>afdaskfdlasjf...</td><td>Jackson</td><td>33</td></tr><tr class="w2p_even even"><td>4</td><td>SUUUUPPPEEEER...</td><td>Jackson</td><td>33</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I've also tried the following views:

```
{{=XML(response._vars[next(iter(response._vars))])}}
```

RESULT (Lost all HTML formatting):

example_data.id,example_data.Firstname,example_data.Lastname,example_data.Age
    1,Jill,Smith,1
    2,Eve,Jackson,33
    3,afdaskfdlasjfkdlsjfklajdfskasjfklsdajfdklsajfklsajfdskalfdjsakldfjklasfjkdlsajfdsakljdklsadcjklasjcklsjackldsjakfldajsfklasdfjklasjfdklajfdsklsjafkldasjfkldasjkldsjcklajsckljackldajsdfklfjkalsncklacnkalsdfjkldasnckldasjckljsdaklfdnfkldsajfdklasjldsk,Jackson,33
    4,SUUUUPPPEEEERRRR LONGGGGG FIRSTTTT NAMEEEE,Jackson,33

Answer (score 0):

All of those methods ultimately result in the DAL `Rows` object being passed to [`SQLTABLE`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Serializing-Rows-in-views) for rendering in the view. By default, fields are truncated to 16 characters. If you want to change that, you will have to call `SQLTABLE` explicitly:

```
{{=SQLTABLE(content, truncate=100)}}
```